# How to create a proxy server using Node.js to resolve CORS issues

Tags: node.js, proxy, cors

Good morning, everyone. I'm a beginner who is just getting started with API integration.
I want to create a page using React that allows users to make payments with Line Pay API. When I click the 'Pay' button, I want to send a POST request with the payment amount via front-end routing to '/linepay'.

```
  // button function
  const handleRecharge = async (amount) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(API_URL + "/linepay", {
      amount,
    }
      console.log(response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

```
  // local API
  router.post("/linepay", async (req, res) => {
    const { amount } = req.body;

    const response = await RechargeService.createOrder(amount);
    console.log(response?.data?.returnCode);
    if (response?.data?.returnCode === "0000") {
      console.log("OK");
      return res.redirect(response?.data?.info?.paymentUrl.web);
    }
  });
```

```
  // Line Pay API
  async createOrder(amount) {
      const linePayBody = {
        ...priceData[amount],
        orderId: parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
        redirectUrls: {
          confirmUrl: "http://localhost:3000/linePay/confirm",
          cancelUrl: "http://localhost:3000/linePay/cancel",
        },
      };
      const headers = this.createSignature(amount);
      return axios.post(`${LINEPAY_SITE}/v3/payments/request`, linePayBody, {
        headers: headers,
      });
    }
```

When I press the payment button, I see that the backend has successfully retrieved API data from the Line Pay server, but the following error occurs in the frontend.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sandbox-web-pay.line.me/web/payment/wait?transactionReserveId=aTR5d3hsaGtoRFVvNGNFaWNGbXAvTFhGYjlqa01RV1lOUEw1ZURhbkF4T01FcEFEZkMwM1hLakZSUGRIQUQwcQ' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/recharge/linepay') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have configured the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header by
`app.use(cors())`

Please help me solve this challenging problem.
Thanks!!

Comment: If you redirect it's not a proxy. You have to send the request from the server